# Problema de Fecha con Grafico de Líneas en Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Estoy trabajando en Python con las librerias de Matplotlib y Pandas.
Lo que quiero hacer son 2 Gráficos de Linea con archivos de BIMBO y CEMEX ambos en formato CSV,
y quiero que en el eje X me grafique una Linea de entre las fechas 2019-05-01 hasta 2019-06-01 (es decir de Mayo a Junio del 2019), pero me sale este error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" y me muestra una grafica vacia, este es mi código Fuente:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

cemex = pd.read_csv('data/linea/CEMEXCPO.MX.csv',index_col=0)
# cemex = pd.to_datetime(cemex, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
cemex = [datetime.date(2019, 5, 30)] * 5


bimbo = pd.read_csv('data/linea/BIMBOA.MX.csv',index_col = 0)
# bimbo = pd.to_datetime(bimbo, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
bimbo = [datetime.date(2019, 5, 30)] * 5

plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(cemex['Low'],'r--',label='Low',alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(cemex['High'],'b--',label='High',alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(cemex['Close'],'g-',label='Close',alpha=1)
plt.title('Cemex')
ax1.set_xlim([datetime.date(2019, 5, 1), datetime.date(2019, 6, 1)])
plt.ylim(7.5, 9.5)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend()

ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(bimbo['Low'],'r--',label='Low',alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(bimbo['High'],'b--',label='High',alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(bimbo['Close'],'g-',label='Close',alpha=1)
plt.title('Bimbo')
ax2.set_xlim([datetime.date(2019, 5, 1), datetime.date(2019, 6, 1)])
plt.ylim(35, 45)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
plt.savefig("graficadelinea.png",dpi=300)
```

Me gustaría que me quede como en la siguiente imagen, porfavor si me pueden ayudar, desde ya muchas gracias![image: Grafico de Linea]

Aqui también dejo en imagen algunas filas de mi DataSet de CEMEX
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, incluye en la pregunta los errores, no los resumas. Puedes [edit] y mostrarlos, por favor

Comment: Buen día, por favor también incluye algunas filas de tus `datasets` como texto ya que sin ellos no es posible reproducir el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error aperece ya sea porque estas usando un datetime en vez de un float en `ax1.set_xlim()` o por que (de lo que esta en el ejemplo proveido) el dataframe original es sustituido por una lista de fechas `cemex = [datetime.date(2019, 5, 30)] * 5`

Ahora bien, dado el ejemplo compartido, parece que lo que se quiere hacer es graficar solo una porcion de los datos y no toda la table (solo el mes de mayo de 2019 en vez de todos los datos de 2018 en adelante). En siguiente ejemplo se filtra con la linea de "mask".

```
accion1 = pd.read_csv("accion1.csv",index_col=0)
accion2 = pd.read_csv("accion2.csv",index_col=0)

# Aqui se crean dos filtro para cada accion, en caso que se quiera cambiar la ventana de alguno de estos
mask_fechas_accion1 = (accion1.index >= "2019-05-01") & (accion1.index <= "2019-06-01")
mask_fechas_accion2 = (accion2.index >= "2019-05-01") & (accion2.index <= "2019-06-01")

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1)
accion1.loc[mask_fechas_accion1,["High","Low", "Close"]].plot(ax=axs[0])
accion2.loc[mask_fechas_accion2,["High","Low", "Close"]].plot(ax=axs[1])
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo, me sirvió 10/10, que Dios lo bendiga.